# 4 columns - fixed-fluid-fluid-fluid

Tags: html, css

I want to make 4 columns with the `<div>` element:

- The width of the 1st column needs to be fixed at 200px.
- The other 3 columns need to dynamically divide the remaining width between them.

```
<div class="column">Column 1 Fixed 200px</div>
<div class="column">Column 2 Fluid</div>
<div class="column">Column 3 Fluid</div>
<div class="column">Column 4 Fluid</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `calc`:

```
.column:nth-child(1) {
    width: 200px;
}

.column:nth-child(n + 2) {
    width: calc((100% - 200px) / 3);
}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/rknbqs5y/)

Answer (score 3):

Just building on @bowheart's answer - You could simplify the CSS a little more:

```
.column {width: calc((100% - 200px) / 3)}
.column:first-child{width: 200px}
```

This way, you're targeting all of them and then isolating the first one.

Answer (score 1):

## Using flexbox

**Compatibility:** [IE11 + and all modern browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) Safari requires the `-webkit-` prefix.

[image: Screenshot]

If the lack of legacy browser support is not an issue, this layout can be achieved very simply:

- The body (or a div wrapper) is given `display: flex` with a height (you can specify any height you wish the columns to have).
- The 3 flexible divs are given `flex: 1` and will grow and shrink evenly.
- The 1 fixed div is given `flex: 0 0 200px` it will not grow or shrink and will remain its default 200px wide.

[Easy guide to Flexbox over on CSS Tricks.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

### Complete Examples

#### With no wrapper

The entire height of the viewport is filled with `width: 100vh` on `<body>`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
body > div {
  flex: 1;
  background: #F00;
}
body > div:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
body > div:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #F90;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

#### With a div wrapper

The wrapper is given a smaller height and an appropriate min / max width.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 50vh;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper > div {
  flex: 1;
  background: #F00;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #F90;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```